# Applying a styleclass to Rich Faces Drop down menu

Tags: html, jsf, richfaces

I am using Rich Faces to design a drop down menu. I want to apply a style class to it.

Please find below my code:

```
<rich:dropDownMenu inputClass="ovalbuttonBig" value="Add Part" direction="bottom-right"  jointPoint="bl" >
    <rich:menuItem submitMode="ajax" value="Covered" action="#{ddmenu.doNew}"/>
    <rich:menuItem  submitMode="ajax"  value="Non Covered" action="#{ddmenu.doOpen}"/>                                          
</rich:dropDownMenu>
```

The `ovalButtonBig` style class isn't getting applied to the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Rich Faces reference guide for `rich:dropDownMenu`, there is nothing like `inputClass` style available.

To override the default style classes, you must apply CSS to the classes attached with this component.

This can be found in [Rich Faces reference guide 3.3](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_dropDownMenu.html) and [Rich Faces reference guide 4.0](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Menus_and_toolbars.html#sect-Component_Reference-Menus_and_toolbars-richdropDownMenu)

Use Developer tool and depending on your requirement override the CSS. As can be seen in the screen shot below, there are standard CSS classes attached with this component which can be understood from the reference guide.

[image]
[image]